# Handling view resizing programatically heights, widths and margins

Tags: ios, ios5, uiview, cgrect, cgrectmake

I am trying to setup a view programatically. Through preference I prefer to programme the views as opposed to using Interface Builder, I feel I have a better control for some reason...

I am setting up a view with two subviews and a button. What I am trying to acheive is the same view when the orientation changes. Initially I thought I needed to calculate the screen size then calculate some divisions to work out the changes, but it appears I can handle on UIViewAutoresizing***

The issue I experience is with the top margin. Here is my code for the subviews.

```
    // Create sub view for Logo
UIView *logoView =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,280)];
[logoView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
logoView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

// Create sub view
UIView *buttonView =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, logoView.bounds.size.height, 320,200)];
[buttonView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
buttonView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

Here is a picture of portrait and landscape where you can see the issue, with the 'white' space.

[image: Portrait]

[image: Landscape]

Comment: Do you want the blue view to take up that white space or the red view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either want the two views (red and blue) to end up with a proportionate amount of space after the rotation:

```
logoView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
buttonView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

Or you want the red view to end up the same size as it started out, and the blue view to adjust to make room for it:

```
logoView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
buttonView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This was driving me crazy and it certainly makes more sense using either of the above, wish I had thought about it more!

Answer (score 0):

use autolayouts . U dont have to deal with any of these issues ...

Comment: How do I use autolayouts, I do not know, any tutorials/examples/information?

Comment: Same applies to this question, this is only available in ios6... I would like the app also available for ios5 at the least.